# Unable to repeat click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is basically a menu toggle feature which I want to repeat but can't achieve the intended unless I refresh the page. Clicking on `.fa-bars` adds class `.animate` to body which slides in the menu from the left, when the menu is visible clicking anywhere outside the menu area, it hides the menu as well as removes the class`.animate` from body.

This only works once then I refresh the page.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(document).on('click', function() 
    {
        if($('body').hasClass('animate')) 
        {
             $('body.animate').on('click', function() 
             {
                  $(this).removeClass('animate');
             });
        } 
        else 
        {
             $('.fa-bars').on('click', function() 
             {
                  $('body').addClass('animate');
             });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he want to close menu when click on body only. This code may help:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fa-bars').on('click', function (evt) {
        $('body').addClass('animate');
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('body').on('click', function () {
        if ($('body').hasClass('animate')) {
            $('body').removeClass('animate');
        }
    });
});
```

Click on fb-bars to open menu

Click on body to close menu if already opened

Comment: Thanks Huy but that code isn't working, it's not even toggling the menu.

Comment: Edited, I add stopPropagation to prevent duplicated event processing